# JavaScript не меняет картинку, но при этом не выдаёт ошибок

Tags: javascript

Тут вырезка с нужными частями кода

HTML:

```
<div class="header wow fadeInUp">
                Лучшие VR очки
            </div>
            <div class="underline wow fadeInUp"></div>
                <div class="vrglasses-container-1">
                    <ul class="vrglasses">
                            <li class="vrglass1 fch"> <button type="submit" onsubmit="changeImage('htc')"> HTC Vive </button> </li>
                        <li class="vrglass1"> + Очки дают возможность погрузиться в качественный VR</li>
                        <li class="vrglass1"> + Огромное количество контента для модели</li>
                        <li class="vrglass1"> - Высокая цена</li>
                        <li class="vrglass1"> Средная цена: (24000 грн)</li>
                            <li class="vrglass2 fch"> <button type="submit" onsubmit="changeImage('xiaomi')"> Xiaomi Mi VR 2 </button> </li>
                        <li class="vrglass2"> + Невысокая цена</li> 
                        <li class="vrglass2"> + Хороший функционал для гарнитуры, работающей со смартфоном</li>
                        <li class="vrglass2"> - Отсутствие возможности прослушивать музыки</li>
                        <li class="vrglass2"> - Приложение на китайском языке</li>
                        <li class="vrglass2"> Средная цена: (1700 грн)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="slider">
                    <img id="img" height="300px" src="../img/htc.jpg">
                </div>  
                <div class="vrglasses-container-2">
                    <ul class="vrglasses">
                            <li class="vrglass3 fch"> <button type="submit" onsubmit="changeImage('oculus')"> Oculus Go - 64GB</button> </li>
                        <li class="vrglass3"> + Возможность автономного использования</li>
                        <li class="vrglass3"> + Большое количество приложений для Oculus</li>
                        <li class="vrglass3"> - Небольшая автономность (до 2 часов)</li>
                        <li class="vrglass3"> Средная цена: (6500 грн)</li>
                            <li class="vrglass4 fch"> <button type="submit" onsubmit="changeImage('bobovr')"> BOBOVR Z6 </button> </li>
                        <li class="vrglass4"> + Недорогой "билет" в мир VR</li>
                        <li class="vrglass4"> + Эргономичность</li>
                        <li class="vrglass4"> - Без телефона бесполезен</li>
                        <li class="vrglass4"> - Есть вопросы к качеству линз</li>
                        <li class="vrglass4"> Средная цена: (1140 грн)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

.inner-third-face {
    width: 98,9vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/background-2.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    border-top: 1px #400D50 solid;
}

.inner-third-face .header {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.inner-third-face .vrglasses {
    opacity: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

.inner-third-face .vrglasses .fch {
    opacity: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.vrglasses-container-1 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 22vw;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #777777;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 3px #0A000B solid;
    float: left;
}

.vrglasses-container-2 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 22vw;
    background-color: #777777;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 3px #0A000B solid;
    float: right;
    height: 60vh;
}

#slider {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 6vw;
    height: 29vw;
}

#img {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px black double;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var slider =  document.querySelector('#slider');
var img = #slider.querySelector('#img');
var images = ['htc.jpg', 'xiaomi.jpg', 'oculus.jpg', 'bobovr.jpg'];
var i = 0;

  window.setInterval (function() {

    img.src = '../img/' + images[i];
    i++;

  },
    1000
  );


var slider =  document.querySelector('#slider');
var img = #slider.querySelector('#img');

function changeImage(company) {
    switch (company) {
      case 'htc':
        img.src = '../img/htc.jpg';
      break;
      case 'xiaomi':
        img.src = '../img/xiaomi.jpg';
      break;
      case 'oculus':
        img.scr = '../img/oculus.jpg';
      break;
      case 'bobovr':
        img.src = '../img/bobovr.jpg';
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: что вот это `var img = #slider.querySelector('#img');` и `var img = #slider.querySelector('#img');` если не ошибка в двух местах?))  и зачем два раза их объявлять?)